# This is my one last try at understanding async-await. Am I correct?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I think I finally understand it after the following paragraph

> If you mark a method with or async modifier, you can use the await
>   operator in the method. When control reaches an await expression in
>   the async method, control returns to the caller, and progress in the
>   method is suspended until the awaited task completes. When the task is
>   complete, execution can resume in the method.

which comes from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2012/06/26/understanding-a-simple-async-program.aspx.

So let's say I have a function

```
public void Caller ( ) 
{
    Something1();
    SomeAsyncMethod();
    Something2();
    Something3();
    Something4();
}

public async void SomeAsyncMethod ( )
{
    Task<string> getWebPageTask = GetWebPageAsync("http://stackoverflow.com");
    Console.WriteLine("Begin");
    string task = await getWebPageTask;
    Console.WriteLine("End");
    // return 
}
```

and for the sake of argument let's say that the time it takes to complete `task` lines up where I specify below

```
    Something2();
    Something3();
    // task would be done at this point
    Something4();
```

Then the flow of execution is actually like

```
    Something1();
    Task<string> getWebPageTask = GetWebPageAsync("http://stackoverflow.com");
    Console.WriteLine("Begin");
    Something2();
    Something3();
    string task = [ string returned by GetWebPageAsync("http://stackoverflow.com") ] 
    Console.WriteLine("End");
    Something4();
```

So it's a lot like a `yield` statement in that the execution toggles between the caller of the method and the body of the method.

Do I understand it now?

Comment: Never use `async void`.  That's your problem.

Comment: The sequence of operations actually depends on your environment. If you're running under Win Forms/WPF, the post-await section of your `SomeMethodAsync` will have to wait until `Caller` (and any of its upstream synchronous callers) have completed, because the post-await continuation can't run while its target thread is busy. If you're running in a console app, the post-await section will execute in parallel with `Something4`. If you're running under ASP.NET, either of the above can happen.

Comment: It is **super confusing** that you have named a string "task" in a program that is full of actual tasks,.

Comment: Read [these articles](https://docs.com/paulo-morgado/8860/async-await-general) to understand `async-await`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Do I understand it now?

No, not quite. The completion of the task stored in `getWebPageTask` does not cause the thread currently running `Something3` to drop what it is doing and run the remainder of `SomeAsyncMethod`. (Unless there is something truly bizarre going on, like one of those methods pumping a message loop.)

Rather, the continuation is scheduled to run at some unspecified time in the future.

How does this work?  Let's suppose you are in a windows forms application, because that's easy to reason about. You have probably noticed that in a winforms application everything is "event driven". That is, when an event happens, somehow mysteriously the event handler executes. This is not magic. There is a loop sitting there at the top that is pulling windows messages off the message queue, decoding them, and determining if there is an event handler associated with them. If there is then the handler runs; it's just an ordinary method invocation.

When a task completes in a windows forms application it puts a message in the queue that means "a task completion event has just occurred; when you process this message, invoke this continuation".

That's why the continuation will be invoked **at some time in the future** -- the message loop isn't going to be running again until all the code that it just invoked returns back to it. If the task completes while that happens then the message will be sitting there in the queue to be dealt with in order.

Now, other control flows are possible. You can configure a thread so that when a task started by that thread completes, the completion is scheduled to run in the future *on a worker thread of the task manager's choice*.  But let's walk before we run; make sure you understand how this works on *one thread* before you try to figure out how it works on multiple threads.

Supposing that your `Caller` method is invoked by the message loop, the actual control flow in a single threaded async program would go like this:

```
message loop invokes Caller
    Caller invokes Something1
        Something1 returns 
    Caller invokes SomeAsyncMethod
        SomeAsyncMethod invokes GetWebPageAsync
            GetWebPageAsync starts fetching a web page and returns a task
        SomeAsyncMethod stores the task
        SomeAsyncMethod writes Begin
        SomeAsyncMethod checks whether the task completed. Let's suppose it did not.
        SomeAsyncMethod makes a delegate that writes "End" and assigns it as the continuation to the task (*)
        SomeAsyncMethod returns
    Caller invokes Something2, which returns
    Caller invokes Something3, which returns
    Suppose at this point the task completes. The IO system queues up a message. (**)
    Caller invokes Something4, which returns
    Caller returns
If there are messages queued up before the completion message, they are processed.
Eventually the message loop sees that there is a queued message saying that a task has completed. It invokes the completion.
    "End" is written.
    The completion returns.
The message loop keeps on pumping messages and doing work.
```

(*) This is a lie of oversimplication. The actual delegate produced is a lot more complicated.

(**) This is a bit of an oversimplification too, but it gets the idea across.

Now, the reader following along carefully will ask "how on earth did the task put a message in the message queue if that thread was busy calling `Something3`? Surely this is every bit as impossible as the processor simply dropping in the continuation while `Something3` is running, right? This is again not actually magic -- though it is considerably more magical than the prosaic event loop! -- and is explained in Stephen Cleary's article "There Is No Thread", which I recommend you read.

Answer (score 1):

It is very different from using `yield`, because `yield` does not do anything with threading.

I highly suggest watching Steve Sanderson's presentation (You'll catch on about 33% of the way through, so no need to watch the full hour). He has an excellent analogy right in the beginning where he talks about a waiter in a restaurant:

You don't want your waiter standing by your table while you eat -- the waiter is better off refilling somebody's water, taking orders, etc. Then, when you are done eating, the waiter comes back and give you your check.

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2287